# Ecommerce data in GTM GA4 Event tag not showing up in GA4 Ecommerce Purchases report

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM on our Product Cart website to fire a GA4 event tag called Product Cart Purchase, with the event name `purchase_from_cart`. When users complete a purchase, they are redirected to a page on the site with `/designer-download` in the URL path, and the query string contains all the info I need for the ecommerce analysis.  Instead of using the data layer, I have defined custom variables using the URL query string and composed a custom Javascript variable called `ecommerce_object` .

In the Ecommerce configuration of this tag, I have `Send Ecommerce Data` checked, with the `Data source` as `Custom Object`, `Ecommerce Object` is the value of the `{{ecommerce_object}}`, and the `ecommerce_object` value is generated like this:

```
  function() {
    return {
      transaction_id: {{transaction_id}},
      value: {{signup_revenue}},
      currency: "USD",
      items: [
        {
        item_id: {{product_id}},
        item_name: {{item_name}},
        currency: "USD",
        price: {{signup_revenue}}
        }
      ]
   };
  }
```

The values `{{transaction_id}}`, `{{signup_revenue}}`, `{{product_id}}` are derived from the query parameters, and `{{item_name}}` is derived from another Javascript custom variable translating the `{{product_id}}` to a string naming the product.  But when I look at the Monetization: Ecommerce Purchase report in Google Analytics, it has no data.

Here's what I've tried:

- GTM preview: Verifies that the tag is firing at the appropriate time and that the parameter values are populated correctly, including the `ecommerce_object`
- GA4 debug view: Shows the product*\_*cart\_purchase event firing with the parameter values intact.
- My ecommerce object has the minimum required data for ecommerce analysis: transaction id, value, currency, array of item objects, and each item object has product id, item name and price.

What am I missing?